# Netty requires sending in the same thread as select() which delays sends

Tags: multithreading, netty

Is it possible for Netty to create a worker thread that does all the sends for a group of sockets?  It appears that currently, netty posts outbound messages to a queue and attempts to wake up the selector which then copies the data into an unused buffer and sends it. This takes time. Is it possible to send directly from a different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible.  Netty has no idea about from which thread a user will call write().  Therefore, it needs a write request queue and a dedicated loop to perform writes.  Otherwise the application will suffer from contention depending on how a user wrote his/her application.  Under load, having a dedicated I/O loop and running a protocol with pipelining seem to yield higher throughput.